# Android Studio - Problema con scroll position (Nested Scroll View)

Tags: android, android-studio, scroll-view

**Descripción:**

Estoy haciendo una app como Duolingo. La cuestión es que tengo una actividad la cual quiero que vean a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede ver un constraint layout que contiene la imagen con la flecha "back" y un text view "idiomas". Luego se puede ver un text view "opciones" y por debajo una **línea marron**. Por último, hay un frame-layout el cual contiene un recycler view con los idiomas.

**Problema:**

El problema es que al entrar en la actividad, el scroll position está justo por debajo de la **línea marron**. Adjunto foto de como se ve al entrar en la actividad:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría que al inggresar en la actividad, el scroll muestre todo, como se ve en la imágen numero 1.

**Intenté con esto (pero simplemente no funciona):**

```
NestedScrollView nested = findViewById(R.id.nested);
nested_categorias.scrollTo(-0,-0);
```

**Adjunto el código XML de mi actividad**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
android:id="@+id/nested"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.ui.INICIO.CATEGORIAS.categorias"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
        android:background="#8d6e63"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgbt_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_back_negro"
            android:tint="#ffffff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_categoria"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
            android:text="Idiomas"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15.5sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgbt_back"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgbt_back"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgbt_back" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_opciones"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="@string/opciones"
        android:textColor="#795548"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraint_bar"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_barra1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#6d4c41"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_opciones" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_idiomas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_barra1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**¿Que puedo hacer para solucionarlo?**

**Gracias por leer!**

Comment: Podrías en ves de implementar opciones dentro del constraint Layout fuera total de este por ejemplo tener como root un linear layout en orientación vertical y luego pones un tu texto view con la línea marrón y luego el nested scroll view debería satisfacer lo que necesitas. No te pongo una respuesta porque ando con el móvil 

Comment: Gracias por responder Alex, pero aun asi no pude entender nada de lo que quisiste decir

Answer (score 0):

tome tu codigo y lo modifique, esta vez tratare de explicar en mas detalles

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/nested"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#8d6e63"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgbt_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:tint="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_categoria"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Idiomas"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15.5sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_opciones"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:text="opciones"
        android:textColor="#795548"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/txt_barra1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#6d4c41"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_opciones" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_idiomas"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_barra1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Vamos por partes:

Si quieres definir un toolbar, ocupa los View correspondientes, el por que es bien simple, esos view ya fueron creados y tienen metodos predefinidos, si quieres puedes crear los tuyos pero en ese casos deberias crearlos como CustomViews y asegurarte de extender de la clase correcta

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#8d6e63"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

       <!-- si quieres agregar algo lo puedes hacer aqui --> 

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Luego tienes esta parte, el donde esta contenido el texto, la barra y el recyclerView

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_opciones"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       ...
        android:text="opciones"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/barra1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#6d4c41"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_opciones" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_idiomas"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barra1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Si te fijas no es necesario un NestedScroll para lo que quieres, ya que lo que vas a cargar va en el RecyclerView y ese tiene su propio scroll, trata siempre evitar tener un recyclerview dentro de un scroll o un nestedscroll es una pesima experiencia de usuario

Pon atencion en esta propiedad en el ConstraintLayout `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` si te fijas con eso lo que haces es que le dices al ConstraintLayout que empiece exacto debajo de toolbar, es muy importante ocuparlo, debes recordar que tu app debe funcionar en difreentes versiones de android y deferentes equipos, por la misma razon, en el toolbar tienes         `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"`

Si quieres ver como funciona el NestedScroll agregalo despues del ConstraintLayout y envuelve el textview la barra y el recyclerview, despues sacala el textview, y ve como cambia el comportamiento, y despues la barra, etc ...

Otro consejo, si vas a ocupar margen `android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"` como ese, reemplazalo por `android:layout_marginStart="10dp"` y si tu intencion es que tu viste no se vea asimetrica define `android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"`, es el mismo margen pero al otro lado, sobretodo en TextView es importante, no solo por estetica si no, debido a internalizacion, en algunos paises se escribe de derecha a izquierda

Finalmente por que utilizar **View** y no un **TexView** para dibujar una barra/linea/raya es mas personal esto pero como desarrollador si veo un textView espero que en algun momento se muestre un texto

PS: sorry por la falta de acentos pero mi teclado esta en thai y no tengo algunos caracteres

Saludos!

Comment: Hola @Francisco, te doy gracias infinitas una vez más por estar ayudandome tanto este último tiempo. Lamentablemente me quitaste el Nested Scroll view. Si te fijas, tengo un Frame Layout el cual contiene fragments los cuales tienen recycler views con más listas de idiomas. Los Nested Scroll los utilizo para que el scroll afecte tanto a la actividad, como a el contenido de los fragments (osea los recycler view). Por si no quedó claro, quiero que el scroll sea del nested y no el del recycler. De todos modos voy a ver si puedo rescatar algo de información de tu respuesta para corregir mi problema

Comment: ahhh ok creo que te entendi, en un rato mas modifico las respuesta

Comment: Por favor. Me sería de gran ayuda!